# Rails: Enable users to choose their roles when signing up on devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, roles

I'm using `devise` for my Rails project to authenticate users. There are several roles that users can choose from (e.g. admin, student, teacher), and I want the users to be able to choose their role **when signing up**.

I've searched around and found ways to set a default role and enable users to change that role later, but I couldn't find a good resource for how to modify the devise controller and view to **allow users to choose their role right away**.

Can someone point me to a tutorial or something that they know would be helpful?

Comment: That sounds really insecure. Do you really want anybody on the internet to be able to become an admin in your application?

Comment: nvm about the admin, I decided to create an enum for any roles beside admin, and then created a column admin (bool) to handle that.

Answer (score 0):

You can set drop down of roles in sign up form.

and permit your parameter like this.

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) do |u|
      u.permit(:role_id,:email, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end
  end
end
```

Hope this will help you.